# Pareto distribution (inverse)

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to find the inverse of the pareto distribuition to find generate numbers, but my result isn't very good. Can somenone help me with the calculations?

The density probablity is defined through the equation $$f(x)=\frac{a-1}{x^a}$$

Comment: What do you mean by the inverse of a distribution ? Do you mean that you want to find the pdf of $Y:=1/X$ where $X$ has a Pareto distribution ?

Comment: No I am trying to implement the inverse method to generate random numbers, so is the inverse of the CDF. But the result in python is so weird that i need to check my math.

Comment: I understand. 1) Is the pdf you give valid for $x > b$ for a certain $b$, and what is the value of $f(x)$ for $0<x<b$ ? 2) Have you obtained an explicit equation $y=F(x)$ of the CDF ? If such is the case, is your issue to get a mathematical expression of $F^{-1}$ or do you want to do it via a Python program ?

Comment: The CDF is the integral of the equation above with limits between 0 and x. Then the result is inverted. I dont need to do it via Python. I just want to check my math. I think i am doing the invertion wrong.

Comment: I am sorry I AM not understanding. I just thought ir was to integrate directly the equation above. I get a result than invert. My result was -x**(-a+1). The invertion is my problema.

Comment: I see now where your problem is. Do you know that cdf $F$, being a primitive function of pdf $f$, is defined "up to an additive constant" ; in the present case, this constant is $\color{red}{1}$, i.e., we have $F(x)=\color{red}{1}-x^{-a+1}$ ; constant $\color{red}{1}$ has been chosen such that $F(x)$ tends to $1$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: I am sorry my pc crashed, but I tried again it worked, the result in python is correct. It just a bit confusing because in the exponential case , you really dont have to consider the constant to obtain a correct result. Thats why I wasnt considering the constant.

Comment: I am sure you have to consider this constant : if $y=1-x^{1-a}$, the inverse is $x=(1-y)^{a-1}=F^{-1}(y)$ which is not at all the same thing that if you haven't the constant $\color{red}{1}$...

Comment: I was doing some calculations and I think I finally understand. Thank you !!